# Laravel can't find class in namespace

Tags: php, model, eloquent, laravel-5

I using Laravel, I have a Model class under App/Models

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

class TodoList extends \Eloquent{
  public function listItems(){
      return $this->hasMany('TodoItem');
  }
}
```

In my Controller I have included the namespace as follows:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

...

use App\Models\TodoItem;
use App\Models\TodoList;

class TodoListController extends Controller
```

My method looks like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $list=TodoList::findOrFail($id);
    return \View::make('todos.show')->with('list', $todo_list);
}
```

but when I call to a request i get the error:

> FatalErrorException in TodoListController.php line 75: Class
>   'App\Models\TodoList' not found

Comment: If you're using Laravel5, model classes doesn't extend Eloquent. They extend Model. Also, check if your TodoList class file is present at app/Models folder.

Answer (score 6):

Trying running `composer dump-autoload`. Basically your classes become cached so you need to tell Laravel to look for newly added classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, just try this :

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
class TodoList extends Eloquent{
  public function listItems(){
      return $this->hasMany('TodoItem');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code from the docs, but for your example. Note the use Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TodoList extends Model {

    //insert public function listItems() here

}
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is in the correct folder and has the same name caption as the Class you want to import.

If the caption of the file "TodoList" is not TodoList.php but Todolist.php for example, Laravel wont find it.

Depending on your setup running "composer dump" might help to refresh autoload files.